# How could I create a custom tabbar similar to segment control?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, ios6, xcode4.5

How could I create a custom tabbar control similar to segment control at a bottom?

On the bottom, there are three tabs (tab1,tab2 and tab3). Tab show like segment control. Every segment index is selected, the navigation bar show will have different views.

Any help or insight into how to achieve this would be great.

Answer (score 1):

you can use Images like you want to set as a background of your `UITabBar`...

otherwise use custom `UITabBarController` , see bellow some links..

1. [custom-uitabbarcontroller-for-the-iphone](http://www.guerrillawebsitedesign.co.uk/wordpress/index.php/2010/09/30/how-to-create-a-custom-uitabbarcontroller-for-the-iphone-with-different-background-images-and-icons-part-1-2/)
2. [iphone-app-implement-a-custom-tab-bar](http://idevrecipes.com/2011/01/04/how-does-the-twitter-iphone-app-implement-a-custom-tab-bar/)
3. [how-to-make-tabbar-in-iphone-sdk code](http://rahulvirja.blogspot.in/2012/05/how-to-make-tabbar-in-iphone-sdk.html)
4. [RXCustomTabBar](https://github.com/rumex/RXCustomTabBar)
5. [Custom TabBar](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=tabbar) /// see this links with many types of UITabBar..

i hope this help you..

Comment: @Sneha see this link for custom Tabbar may you got perfect tabbar which you want from this many demos for it.. http://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=tabbar :)